# javascript if url has query string, set cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, query-string

How do i set a cookie if the url has a query string '?no_redirect=1'?

I'm not getting any cookies being set. Currently i have

```
function cookieQuery() {
    var referrer = "//domain.local";
    if (document.referrer) {
        var no_redir = 'no_redirect';
        var url = window.location.href;
        if(url.indexOf('?' + no_redir) != 1)
            return true;
        else if(url.indexOf('&' + no_referral) = 1)
           $.cookie('no_referral', 'true');
                }
            }
```

Comment: And what happens to your code?

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator and not the comparison operator on this line:
`else if(url.indexOf('&' + no_referral) = 1)`

change it to `else if(url.indexOf('&' + no_referral) == 1)` and assuming the rest of your code is correct, it should work.